# jquery selector id,class,rel etc where value greater than a given number

Tags: jquery

I would like to fade all divs that have a numeric attribute greater than or less than a given number.

Something like `$( "div[id$=2]" ).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);`

but I would like to use the ">" or "<" operator instead of "="

basically I would name all my divs something like

```
<div id="22">text</div>
<div id="35">text</div>
<div id="40">text</div>
```

and then use

```
$( "div[id$>35]" ).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
```

to fade out the last cell

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your HTML is not valid. `ID` attribute should not start with a number.

do it like this,

```
<div id="div22" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div35" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div40" class="fade">text</div>
```

then jQuery

```
var divs = $('.fade').map(function(){
                if (this.id.replace('div','') > 35) return '#'+this.id;
           }).get().join(',');

$(divs).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
```

[You may play it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fv9jN/)

this works too,

```
var divs = $('.fade').map(function(){
            if (this.id.replace('div','') > 22) return this;
       }).get();
$(divs).fadeOut("slow");
```

as [Russ Cam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831/russ-cam/) suggested to use filter,

```
var divs = $('.fade').filter(function(){
            return (this.id.replace('div','') > 22);
       });
$(divs).fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: Using filter would probably be easier

Answer (score 2):

This isn't valid HTML.  An `id` may not start with a digit.  Instead, you may find the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector helpful.  You can use, e.g. `td:gt(4)` to find those tds with 0-index > 4, or `#container div:gt(1)` to find divs in container with index > 1.

Comment: The only problem with using :gt is that it assumes that the numbered divs appear in numerical order on the page which may/may not be the case.