# How to find the id with the greatest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC web page using Razor. Versions are Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3, Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3, .NET Framework 4.7, C# and Javascript.

A view will have a table with these rows:

```
<tr id="level01_01"> ... </tr>
<tr id="level01_02"> ... </tr>
<tr id="level01_03"> ... </tr>
```

I need to know with `jQuery` which is the id for the latest row. In the above example is `level01_03`.

I create these rows with C# so I can add the input hidden with the latest id as value.

If I want to find it without an input hidden, I don't know how to do it. In this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3509181/68571) I've found how to get an id with a value greater than other, but this is not what I'm looking for:

```
<div id="div22" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div35" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div40" class="fade">text</div>
```

then jQuery

```
var divs = $('.fade').map(function(){
                if (this.id.replace('div','') > 35) return '#'+this.id;
           }).get().join(',');
$(divs).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
```

**BUT THIS IS NOT WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR.**

I'm looking to get the id with the greatest number. In this example the id is `level01_03`.

How can I get the id with the greatest id?

Comment: $("tr").last().attr("id") ?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting and don't telling why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to return the highest id value.

```js
var ids = $("tr[id^='level01_']").map(function() {
  return parseInt(this.id.replace("level01_", ""), 10);
}).get();

var highest = Math.max.apply(Math, ids);
console.log(highest)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="level01_01"> ... </tr>
  <tr id="level01_02"> ... </tr>
  <tr id="level01_03"> ... </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several possible ways of doing this.

Firstly, assuming that the highest `id` will be the last one, you can just get the `tr:last` and read it's `id`:

```
var lastId = $('table tr:last').prop('id').spit('_')[1];
```

Alternatively, if the values are incremental you can just count the total number of `tr` elements:

```
var lastId = $('table tr').length;
```

Finally, if they are not in order you can use `map()` to build an array of the values, then `Math.max` to get the highest:

```js
var highestId = Math.max.apply(Math, $('table tr').map(function() {
  return parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1], 10);
}).get());

console.log(highestId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="level01_10"></tr>
  <tr id="level01_221"></tr>
  <tr id="level01_3"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to modify to find the greatest id from different sets of ids. I will something like `level01_01`, `level01_02`, `level02_01`, `level02_02` and `level02_03`. If I want to get the greatest id for `level01` or `level02` or another string (`levelxx`). How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`jQuery.filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
var divs = $('.fade').filter(function() {
  return (+this.id.replace('div', '') > 35);
});

$(divs).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div22" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div35" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div40" class="fade">text</div>
```

**To get filtered IDs:**

```js
var divs = $('.fade').filter(function() {
  return (+this.id.replace('div', '') > 35);
}).map(function() {
  return this.id;
});

console.log(divs.get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div22" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div35" class="fade">text</div>
<div id="div40" class="fade">text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for the id with the greatest number. The greater number than the others ids, not the id with a number greater than 35.

Answer (score 0):

This function will set `$el` to the row with the highest valued Id.

```
var $el, max = 0;

$("tr").each(function() {
  var i = parseInt(this.id.replace(/.*_(\d+)$/, "$1"));

  if (i > max) {
    max = i;
    $el = $(this);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if your TR having ascending ID than you can simply get last TR id like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
        <title>Title Goes Here</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert($("#tbl tr:last").attr("id"));
        });
        </script>       
    </head> 
    <body> 
<table class="data" id="tbl">
  <tr id="level01_01">
    <th>Entry Header 1</th>
    <th>Entry Header 2</th>
    <th>Entry Header 3</th>
    <th>Entry Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="level01_02">
    <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="level01_03">
    <td>Entry Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="level01_04">
    <td>Entry Last Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by comparing `id` as string like this code below:

```js
var max = '';
$("#test tr").each(function() {
  if (this.id.localeCompare(max) > 0) {
    max = this.id;
  }
});
console.log(max)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <tr id="level01_01"> ... </tr>
  <tr id="level01_02"> ... </tr>
  <tr id="level01_153"> ... </tr>
  <div id="res"></div>
</table>
```